# How to merge multiple pyspark dataframes where all dataframes have same index columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I created pyspark dataframes using below code:

```
df_1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_1)
df_2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_2)
df_3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_3)
df_4 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_4)
```

Each of these dataframe has 2 common columns which we can use as index columns and the other columns are different. I want to merge both the dataframes.

df_1

| Firm | Product | Date | Parameter-A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Firm-A | Product-1 | 30-01-2019 | 3 |

df_2

| Firm | Product | Date | Parameter-B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Firm-A | Product-1 | 30-01-2019 | 4 |

df_3

| Firm | Product | Date | Parameter-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Firm-A | Product-1 | 30-01-2019 | 5 |

df_4

| Firm | Product | Date | Parameter-D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Firm-A | Product-1 | 30-01-2019 | 6 |

I want the resulting dataframe to look like below.

df_result

| Firm | Product | Date | Parameter-A | Parameter-B | Parameter-C | Parameter-D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Firm-A | Product-1 | 30-01-2019 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

I tried below code but its only working for pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

df = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]
df_result = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right, how= 'left', on=['Firm', 'Product']), df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
merged_df = df1.join(df2,on=['Firm', 'Product'], how='outer')\
   .join(df3,on=['Firm', 'Product'], how='outer')\
   .join(df4,on=['Firm', 'Product'], how='outer')\
   .join(df5,on=['Firm', 'Product']  how='outer')\
   .na.drop()
   .show()

display(merged_df)
```

Comment: Hi , I may have to join 4 dataframes now in a similar way.

Comment: I have updated the above code. Take a look. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: don't forget to upvote the answer so that others can also find this helpful

Comment: Yup , did it..thanks. Also, I didn't use na.drop() because I need to have nulls in my data for now.