# Pyspark adding columns to existing dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to add multiple column to to right how can i do that?

`Attributes = ["RequestTypePesId","AgentId","UpdatedBy","CauseType","OriginatingSystem"] for i in Attributes: a = df2load.select(i).distinct() b = a.join(b,a.select(i) ==  b.select(i),"fullouter")`

Output should be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9moc.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71966176/9658895

and since you’re new, you might find this article useful:
[“Hello World” of PySpark for Python & Pandas User [Pandas Vs PySpark]](https://sargupta93.medium.com/hello-world-of-pyspark-for-python-pandas-user-pandas-vs-pyspark-dba7e626556e)

Lastly, before you ask your next question, please make sure that you have followed standard protocol of asking a question. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWl99g9El2A) might help you.